# Baxter Installation on ROS groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Baxter on ROS groovy from catkin workspace where the SDK resides, and use wstool to install and update. This is waht i am supposed to do:-

```
    $ cd ~/ros_ws/src
    $ git clone git@github.com:RethinkRobotics/baxter_simulator.git
# IMPORTANT EARLY-DEV-RELEASE STEPS:
    $ cd baxter_simulator
    $ git checkout early_interface_dev
    $ cd ..
    $ wstool init # need to do this only if this is a new workspace where this command was not executed before.
    $ wstool merge baxter_simulator/baxter_simulator.rosinstall
    $ wstool update
```

But after i type in  i get this error message. please explain the reason and solution.

```
sa@svs-FX6860:~/catkin_ws/src/baxter_simulator$ git checkout early_interface_dev
error: pathspec 'early_interface_dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193223/baxter-installation-on-ros-groovy/) by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error usually means that the branch you're trying to check out doesn't exist.

Since the repository in question doesn't exist or isn't public, you should probably contact Rethink directly for further support.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on 2015-02-02**:
I just skipped that error-ridden step and proceeded with other steps and things worked out. I have not yet rationalised why it should be so. Still things worked out!